# Best Setup for a Java EE Developer Machine

Tags: java, programming

I have a dual-boot machine, Windows 7 and Ubuntu 12.04.

When I'm using Windows, I have a C:\dev directory that, say, is my "root folder" under which I have all the tools (C:\dev\jdk1.7 for JDK, C:\dev\eclipse for Eclipse and so on).

How can I setup something (functional and) similar in my Ubuntu, say, under my /home folder?

Are there some kind of "best setup" for a linux-based Java EE **developer machine**? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I have something similar too, only thing is Java typically installs itself to the `bin` folder.  I really don't think there's any workaround for this if you install via aptitude.  You may have to manually execute the install executable and point to the folder then set the $PATH variable.

So I keep my IDEs (netbeans, eclipse, springsource) libraries and frameworks(grails, apache commons, joda, ect) and version control repositories (git, svn, hg) in their own folder in the $HOME folder.

Note that the IDE will only work if you install via download rather than apt-get.