# Properly set up java development environment

Tags: java, directory, eclipse, jdk

I am a java developer mainly coding on win environment. I am planning to move to Ubuntu and I would like to know what is the best way to setup my jave, ide, maven and others.

Under Windows I would typically have a D:\dev dir (note D:\ is an SSD drive) in which I put apache-tomcat, apache-maven jdk and so on, but under linux (ubuntu) the directory hierarchy seems to be very important.

If I correctly understand I should install my eclipse and servers under /opt and maybe /usr/local. Unfortunately this way I will not profit from my fast SSD drive under /dev/sdb that I usually mount on /media/fast.

This leads to my question. What is the "appropriate" way of installing and configuring the "usual" set of dev instruments for a java developer under ubuntu like

- JDK
- Maven
- eclipse
- mysql
- apache tomcat

Note * My question is somewhat similar to this one:
[Best Setup for a Java EE Developer Machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164862/best-setup-for-a-java-ee-developer-machine) which was not very well answered imo.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  **;-)** What is "appropriate" and "usual" is defined in the [FHS](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml), so please be more specific to your needs as the Linux File system is very flexible and you can have a ton of hard drives all plugged into the same file system without having to worry about drives...

Answer (score 1):

After some digging I managed to pull this url:

http://sukharevd.net/environment-for-j2ee-development-under-ubuntu.html

It shows how to install the most important components for JEE development under ubuntu.

Please also consider @Fabby's comment on FHS in the original question:

http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/fhs.shtml